# Eye detection and Exception handling

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, object-recognition

This is my function that I have used to detect my eyes and then transmit some co-ordinates.

```
void detectAndDisplay(cv::Mat frame)
{
cv::Mat im1,im2;
std::vector<Rect> eye;
Mat frame_gray;
cv::cvtColor(frame,frame_gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray,eye,1.1,2,0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,cv::Size(30,30));
for( int i = 0; i < eye.size(); i++ )
{
rectangle(frame,Point (eye[i].x,eye[i].y),Point (eye[i].x+eye[i].width, eye[i].y+eye[i].height),Scalar(255,0,0),4,8,0);
Mat noseROI = frame_gray(eye[i]);

    x1=eye[i].x;
    y3=eye[i].y;
    x2=eye[i].width;
    y2=eye[i].height;
}   
imshow("Camera Feed",frame);
}
```

x1,x2,y2,y3 are global variables and I am using TCP/IP socket program to transmit the data to some other program. The problem is that after identifying the eyes once, if they go out of focus the program stops working and an error message is displayed saying that there is an exception which is not handled at the for loop. The error persists if I enclose the for loop in a try-catch block. It might be a run-time exception. What to do to get rid of it?

Comment: What is the exception saying?

Comment: I think it might be an `std::out_of_range` coming from the `vector`'s `operator[]`.

Comment: @vasile-The exception says-> Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.